# Create folder in mounted blob

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I mount my blob container in azure databricks

I can read my data from blob 'input'

I do transformation on my data and store them in blob "output"

problem: when i mount the contrainer, "output" blob does not exist

So when i try to write my output data I have error message

> No such file or directory: '/dbfs/mnt/data/output/file_name.xlsx'

with `/dbfs/mnt/data` mounted conteners

Edit:

i'm using a strange way to write my data, I use follwing function:

```
def creation(df_MA,file,file_path): 
  df_MA.to_excel(file)
  shutil.copy2(file,file_path)
  #copyfile(file, file_path)
  os.remove(file)
```

with df_MA: created file

file: file name

file_path: /dbfs/mnt/data/output/file_name.xlsx

the function write my df_MA in databricks root folder of data brick then it's suposed to move it in my path

**Edit2**:

mouting blob

```
mount_point="/mnt/data/"
 dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = source,
  mount_point = mount_point,
  extra_configs =      {"secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "keyvault", key = "key")})
```

Comment: How do you mount the container and what is the mount point?

Comment: I mean the steps you mount the blob to databricks. Not just the mount point.

Comment: that the only command I use to mount the blob to databricks... Then I access my data in folder /data/input with (for example):  'df_sp = pd.read_excel("/dbfs/mnt/data/Input/ref/doc_1.xlsx", header=1)'

Comment: Maybe you use the wrong path, try to use the path `"dbfs:/mnt/data/output/file_name.xlsx"` to read the file.

Comment: reading file is working well, its creating a new blob in the container that doesn'nt work. For example I would like to create blob `"/dbfs/mnt/data/output/file_name.xlsx`

Comment: Maybe you can try the example code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--dbutils) to create files. And you can try to create the directory output first.

Comment: Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208703/discussion-between-akhetos-and-charles-xu).